# quicksort matlab, recursive function

Tags: matlab, recursion

I need to write a recursive function embedded with quicksort algorithm. 
I'm having trouble when updating the new boundaries. y is a matrix and m is the num of the row needs to be sorted.Please help...

```
function [y]=quicksort(y,left,right,m)

i=left;
j=right;
num=randi(length(y)); % pick a random element in the array as pivot
pivot=y(m,num);

if i <= j %find the element fits criteria below before i overlaps j.
while y(m,i) < pivot
    i = i + 1;
end
while y(m,j) > pivot
    j = j - 1;
end
    ytmp=y(:,j);
    y(:,j)=y(:,i);
    y(:,i)=ytmp;
    i = i + 1;
    j = j - 1;  
%swap the positions of the two elements when y(m,j) < pivot < y(m,i)

else 
return
end

return 
[y]=quicksort(y,i,right,m);  %update the boundaries.
[y]=quicksort(y,left,j,m);   %recursively call the function.
```

Comment: (1) fix your indentation please. (2) expand on where exactly you are stuck (3) why don't you make your recursive function only accept a vector and then make a wrapper function that extracts row `m` from matrix `y` and passes that to your recursive function.

Comment: @Dan I would assume that they are attempting to sort the entire matrix based on row `m`. @YYCCC I don't think your last `return` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have done some errors. However, since this seems to be homework I will give you some concrete hints and examples instead of posting the right answer directly. I also limit this to a single vector to keep the answer simpler and more concise.

First, you want to swap **all** elements which are on the wrong side of the pivot element, not only the first element. So the tip is to use a while loop. You will however still need to do the swapping somewhere, so you will need an if-statement somewhere as well. Secondly, the last return will always be executed. This means that you will never enter the recursion. Try to instead use a condition where you only continue iterating in case the number of elements left exeeds one.

```
if (i < right)
    y=qsort(y,i,right);  %update the boundaries.
end
if (left < j)
    y=qsort(y,left,j);   %recursively call the function.
end
```

Hope this information is enough. Good luck!